# Celerybeat tasks is fetching the same info even if it has changed. (possible caching) How can i disable this

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery, celerybeat

I have a task set up in celery beats that runs every 2 minutes. 
It takes the if loop based on the existence of a DB object `self.dbObject = Patch.find_by_status('READY')` 
I switch on the worker and the code runs fine. But when I switch the DB from `READY` State to any other state this doesn't reflect on the next run. Does celery cache this data somewhere? I am not using a backend config for celery. If this is caching can I disable or remove it somehow?

The worker restart helps. but my app cannot afford that.

```
def petchme(self):
    self.dbObject = Patch.find_by_status('READY')
    if self.dbObject:
        print('Patch this')
    else:
        print('No patchgroup(s) in pipeline')
```

Answer (score 1):

> Does celery cache this data somewhere?

No, celery does not cache your database accesses.  More likely is that your `Patch` class is doing some sort of caching.  If you **really** want to, you can even set celery to kil workers after performing some number of tasks (like 1).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @2ps, That was the issue. My DbObject was not getting the latest data from the DB in the first place adding a db.session.commit() helped solve the issue.

```
def petchme(self):
    db.session.commit()
    self.dbObject = Patch.find_by_status('READY')
    if self.dbObject:
        print('Patch this')
    else:
        print('No patchgroup(s) in pipeline')
```